# pass multiple parameters in wso2 apimanager 2.1.0

Tags: url, parameters, wso2, wso2-api-manager

need to pass multiple parameters in wso2 api-manager, i looked into this blog, http://vvratha.blogspot.in/2015/01/adding-url-parameters-in-wso2-apimanager.html.
the author has mentioned how to do it,but she has mentioned to create a new sequence, not getting where(i mean, need the path to create a file) and name of the file.

NOTE: i m only using api-manager and not developer tooling.

Comment: You can write in a text file (save as xml )and store in registry. Then associate that with your proxy. Im not using wso2 stack for long. But there should be options for that at publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/… if anybody faces the problem in future go through this link also addition to the above link mentioned by @Bee. Well this link was directly referred by the author of yenlo.com @RobBrouwers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create sequence file and upload it in publisher UI.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-CreateanduploadmanuallyintheAPIPublisher

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly. the author in the above-mentioned link has answered beautifully, all I needed was path save the .xml file, and I got it through your link.

Comment: the path is <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences directory.

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Map+the+Parameters+of+your+Backend+URLs+with+the+API+Publisher+URLs if anybody faces the problem in future go through this link also. well this link was directly referred by the author of yenlo.com  @Rob Brouwers

Comment: i dont want to install developer studios, is there any other way to do it? just with api-manager.

Comment: What exactly what the link says.

Comment: at the begining of the doc "this link uses developer studios..."

Comment: Refer "Create and upload manually in the API Publisher" section.